# For the purposes of USCIS I-864, what proves you're a US Citizen?

Tags: usa, immigration, citizenship, uscis

The information on [I-864ez: Checklist of Required Initial Evidence (for informational purposes only)](https://www.uscis.gov/i-864ez) says,

> Checklist of Required Initial Evidence (for informational purposes only)
>
> - Proof that you are a U.S. citizen, U.S. national, or lawful permanent resident;

The actual filing instructions mention nothing about this? What satisfies "proof" there? What do I need to attach to an i-864ez to show that I am a US citizen? Does a copy of a passport work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your US birth certificate if you were born in the US, consular report if you're US citizen by birth but was born outside the US, copy of your naturalization certificate or citizenship certificate if applicable, or a copy of your passport - these are the usual documents proving your citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

The [I-864 page](https://www.uscis.gov/i-864) checklist, as well as the [I-864 instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-864instr.pdf) section "Checklist", clarify that proof of US citizen, US national, or permanent resident status is only needed for an I-864 that is being completed by a "joint sponsor", "substitute sponsor", or sponsor of an employment-based petition where the company is 5% or more owned by the beneficiary's relative. It is not needed for an I-864 that is being completed by the petitioner of an I-130 family-based petition, since such a petitioner already had to prove their citizenship or permanent residency when filing the I-130.

I don't think that I-864EZ can be filed by a joint sponsor or substitute sponsor; that's probably why proof of status is not mentioned in the I-864EZ instructions. I don't know why it is mentioned on the I-864EZ page checklist; it is probably a mistake.

Comment: I learnt that with the American bureaucracy the safest course of action is to just follow the instructions to the letter. They want proof of citizenship even if it doesn't make sense? Attach it anyway.

Comment: @littleadv but if you follow the instructions for form I-864EZ to the letter (meaning all the instructions in both i864ez.pdf and i864ezinstr.pdf), you _won't_ include documentary evidence of US citizenship.  So the problem here seems to be, at least in part, to determine what constitutes "the instructions."

Comment: @phoog  This doesn't actually appear in the "checklist" section of the form instructions, only on the website, but I'd attach it anyway since it appears somewhere in their lists.

Comment: @littleadv the real problem here is there are _soooo_ many lists. And I imagine 50% of immigration filings are spousal and in the same shoes I'm in. They need call it "Online Pre-Approval" (I-130), with one list like you file it online. And the concurrent I-485/I-864/I-765/I-693/I-131, the "All Access Green Card" with one checklist like we need to file in person. I promise that's how their non-reptilian citizens will view this process.